# How do I SSH to a linux web app service in Azure via github workflow?

Tags: linux, azure, ssh, github-actions

I have a linux web app service running in Azure. During the github workflow deploy, I'd like to connect to the server (SSH) and run a command. I have the following, but it always stops and hangs when I create an SSH session.

Anybody know how I would go about running commands in the SSH session and then exiting out of it so my workflow can continue?

This is just a proof of concept below:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/cli@v1
        with:
          inlineScript: |
            az login --service-principal -u ${{ secrets.AZ_APP_ID }} -p ${{ secrets.AZ_PASSWORD }} --tenant ${{ secrets.AZ_TENANT }}
    
      - name: Add webapp extension
        uses: azure/cli@v1
        with:
          inlineScript: |
            az extension add --name webapp

      - name: Create ssh terminal
        uses: azure/cli@v1
        with:
          inlineScript: |
            az webapp ssh -n blankerbot -g blankerbot_group

      - name: ls the directory
        run: |
          ls
```

I've also tried the following after logging in:

```
        uses: azure/cli@v1
        with:
          inlineScript: |
            az webapp create-remote-connection --subscription ${{ secrets.AZ_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }} --resource-group blankerbot_group -n blankerbot -p 4301

      - name: SSH Connect
        run: |
          ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 4301 && ls
```

But I get the same issue. It just hangs when run in a github workflow. If I add an `&` at the end, it just immediately finishes and tries to run ssh, without waiting for the create-remote-connection to be established.

When I run it from my terminal, I just get the following, indicating that it's running and waiting for me to either SSH or quit:

[image]

There is also a github action someone has created, which looks cool: https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action. The problem is that connecting to an Azure Web App Service container (if it's not public) requires a tunnel. The `az webapp ssh` command and the `az webapp create-remote-connection` command essentially create a ssh tunnel - they create an ssh server that runs on localhost, authenticates you, and tunnels to the real ssh server. So if you're connecting through the az tunnel, you don't have a public host, username, password, etc.

Comment: Looks like [`az webapp ssh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#code-try-29) doesn't support a non-interactive mode. You might want to try https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action instead.

Comment: We ca use [ssh-command-action@v1](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ssh-command) in the workflow file to do SSH.

Comment: Thanks @Azeem. Do you know how to get an SSH username and password for https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action

Comment: @Trevor: Please look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session#open-ssh-session-from-remote-shell and https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/05/07/New-SSH-Experience-and-Remote-Debugging-for-Linux-Web-Apps.html. Might be helpful. You can look at other options such as `scp` and `rsync` to sync your artifacts. (Not tested)

Comment: Hi @Trevor. Did you finally find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use the command [`az webapp create-remote-connection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session#open-ssh-session-from-remote-shell) to open a local SSH tunnel instead. Use the `--port` option to specify a specific local port.

Then you can use a normal SSH action using the host/port of the tunnel: `127.0.0.1:<port>` with the username `root` and password `Docker!`. This will allow you to run any ssh commands in a non-interactive manner just as you would with any typical ssh connection.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and for being willing to help. I am now using this action, but it also just hangs there in the same way. In github, it just stays yellow forever, never finishing. And if I run this interactively from my local terminal it is successful, but the last line says, "Ctrl+C to close" ... indicating that it's waiting for me to either close it or enter the ssh command.

Comment: Ah, you'll want to background the command (by appending a `&` at the end) so your script can continue with the tunnel open in the background @Trevor -- I'm on my phone right now, but I'll try to edit the answer with a concrete example when I get home

Comment: I actually did that as well ... added the ampersand at the end ... but it doesn't wait long enough for the command to finish before i enter the ssh command. Again, thank you for the help. Every little bit teaches me something new. I've updated the question to include some of my experimentation.

Comment: Oh, I see @Trevor I just read your edit. Hmm. I wouldn't have expected that behavior. It might have something to do with the actions environment. I wonder if you can use a single job step that performs both shell commands (`az ... &` and `ssh ...`) in a single `run: |` block. Maybe give it a shot locally and see if you can get it to work in a single script file, then see if you can replicate in GHA.

Comment: I've tried everything I can think of. I cant get it to work. I don't think any of the `az` commands let you send an SSH command in a non-interactive way. At the end of the day, all I'm trying to do is make my deploys faster. I just want to not have to transfer 10k files to the server every time I deploy. I thought if I zipped up my artifact and deployed it to the server, then I could just run an SSH command to unzip it. That was three days ago. If you know of any other ways to make deploys not take so long transferring thousands of files ... I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

For me using **az webapp ssh** and **expect** in github actions worked.

```
- name: "SSH into container"
  run: |
        sudo apt-get install -y expect
        expect -c "
        spawn az webapp ssh -n MyUniqueAppName -g MyResourceGroup
        expect \"#\"
        send \"pwd\r\"   # replace with any linux command to test
        expect \"#\"
        send \"exit\r\"
        "
```

Make sure to login using az login or through azure/login@v1 before running the above step.